# when i use jquery val(value) function why focus move only in IE?

Tags: jquery

there are value1 input box(id = value1) , value2 input box(id = value2), result(id = result) input box
if someone insert value1 and value2 I wanted to add value1 and value2

my code

```
var value1 = $("#value1").val();
var value2 = $("#value2").val();
$("#result").val(value1 + value2);
```

but when result inserted in result inputbox focus moved from value2 input box
to result input box only in IE (in chrome didn't move)
and when i changed my code to pure javascript focus didn't move in both IE and Chrome
I want to know the reason

Comment: I don't know jquery, but I strongly assume that there is a function to focus an input, so if you want the result input to be focused, use that function; since jquery cares about browser differences (AFAIK), this will work in nearly all browsers. If you want to know the reason for the different behavior, you might study the source code of jquery. Regarding pure Javascript, why should the browser move the focus to the field where text was inserted? I am quite sure that specifications neither require nor forbid this, so browsers might behave differently even with pure Javascript.

Comment: Add your HTML and the full jquery code which you are using to do this. then someone can know the reason. @Jeonghee Lee

Comment: Can you update your question to include a working snippet that demonstrates the problem?  Are you 100% sure there's no other code that's causing the focus?

Comment: "why focus move in IE" - short answer:  **it doesn't**.  (and if it did, this site would be full of questions asking why and what to do about it).  You clearly have some other code that's causing the problem.  Here's a fiddle for testing and tested in Chrome, IE11 and Edge: https://jsfiddle.net/87sgcvnp/